# Passing data from one route view to another

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-services, ng-view

I want to pass some values from one view to another in Angularjs using ui-Router.
I don't want to use $rootScope to save data or create a new services ( as I have many views that pass small bits of data so creating new jsfile for few lines code is not fun). A super-minified example of what I want to do is:

**Controller of View 1**
`$scope.goodFood = 10
 $scope.badFood = 2`

**Controller of View 2**
`$scope.results = 10 - 2 (from view 1's scope)`

Is there any quick way to do these kinds of small operations ?

Comment: $stateParams https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Comment: stateparams is for changing between states but here i'm inside a single state containing multiple views (templates & controllers).

Comment: why don't you pass the param to your child view?

Comment: you mean something like this $state.go('view2', {param1: $scope.goodFood, param2: $scope.badFood} ? sorry i'm just recently using angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to use $rootScope to save data or create a new services ( as I have many views that pass small bits of data so creating new jsfile for few lines code is not fun)

There is no need to create a new service for new bits of data. Simply create a value service with an object:

```
app.value("viewData", {});
```

Then simply add new properties as needed:

```
app.controller("viewCtrl", function(viewData) {
    viewData.newProp = "new info";
    console.log(viewData.oldProp);
});
```

As value services are singletons, changes to the contents of the object will survive view changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specified the approach that you wanted to follow, you should create the following

```
$stateProvider
    .state('view2', {
        url: "/view2/:param1/:param2",
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            console.log($state.params.param1+"-"+$state.params.param2);
        }
    });
```

and from where ever you want to call

```
$state.go('view2',{param1:'10', param2:'2'});
```

But in general it is advised that you keep these values in a service or some where stored. With the application growing you may have to use few more attributes to compute

Comment: You can specify what parameters to receive even though the parameters don't appear in the url. See [Using Parameters without Specifying Them in State URLs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to store all the data directly into the $routeParams either through route or query string.

```
routeUrl: /foods/:quality/:stars
```

then in your controller you can access

```
$routeParams.quality - $routeParams.stars
```